# Can you copy an in-cell image to another cell using app script?

Tags: image, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is it currently possible to copy an in-cell image from say `Sheet_A` to another specified cell in `Sheet_B`?

I am trying to build a catalogue where I can retrieve such images with a search function on google sheets. Can someone help me out?

Comment: I think that knowing how your image is put into a cell help thinking a solution. So, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet?

Comment: Thanks for replying, Tanaike. So far, I've got it to work using copyTo. I think it works well for my case!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved, how about posting it as an answer? It will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

It was solved using copyTo. Let me know if you want a sample sheet!!

Comment: Offering a code snip that shows how you solved this is extremely helpful to future readers of this question.